# Are Kubernetes pods that use host networking assigned a pod IP that can be accessed using a Service resource?

Tags: kubernetes, hostnetwork

If a Kubernetes pod is defined with host network enabled, is the application running on this pod accessible from the Service resource using the app selector?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Host network means it will use the host system's network. Services are created in pod network which is separate. So it can not be accessed that way. You can access a pod with host network directly using the IP of the host system. You should avoid using host network though for various reasons.

Here is an [article](https://sookocheff.com/post/kubernetes/understanding-kubernetes-networking-model/) to understand it more deeply.

Comment: Understood (as a note: the host network is enabled because the app in the pod also needs to process SS7 messages received over multi-homed SCTP).So if an HTTP client application running in the pod network needs to access the server application in the pod running in the host network, can I still create a Service resource without an app selector and use Endpoints (the host IPs / ports) of the server app? This would provide for the server app access across the entire Kubernetes cluster (the server app would be deployed as a DaemonSet).

Comment: thanks for including the linked article, very interesting!